# Prevent create-react-app TS from compiling minified libraries

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, eslint

In our project we have some minified libraries that are sort of a black box. They are really old and they're proprietary software (so there's no typing or GitHub repo or anything).

We're exploring moving to create-react-app with Typescript, but we haven't found a way for it to ignore this files when starting/compiling the project.

The errors we're getting are:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/minified-files/some-lib.min.js
  Line 11:57:      'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 11:69:      'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 11:7435:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Here's what we've tried:

1. add `"exclude": [ "./src/minified-files/*" ]` to `tsconfig.json`
2. add `src/minified-files/*` to `.eslintignore`

Nothing has worked so far, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `.eslintignore` is the solution, however I had to use `EXTEND_ESLINT=true`, since I'm using CRA